# Spring Validation using annotation

Tags: spring, validation, eclipselink, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I currently have an application which is in Spring Data JPA(Using EclipseLink).
I am working on writing Validations for that.
Can you someone help me with tutorial links on writing Validation using annotations and in effective way please ?

Thank you in advance,
lucky

Answer (score 0):

For validation you can use oval validation http://oval.sourceforge.net/

It's simple and effective way to implement validation in your project.

Comment: Even for writing Custom Constraints ??

Comment: Yes. You can use http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#using-checkwith. There is some example on oval repository https://svn.code.sf.net/p/oval/code/trunk/src/test/java/net/sf/oval/test/validator/CheckWithConstraintTest.java